# Determine if the series converges/diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I came across this problem in my book:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{e^n \sqrt{n}}$$

I don't really know the approach to solving this off the bat, can this be solved by the comparison test while using the limit comparison test? Or will this require the ratio test?

If it is the comparison test, I jsut want to know what to compare it to? Would it be 1/e^n?

Also:

```
n + 4^n
_______
n + 6^n
```

Would this be compared to 4^n/6^n? Does something raised to the n power take priority over n?

Comment: I would compare to $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{n}}$, which is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: "Does something raised to the $n$ power take priority over $n$?" See [here](http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/06/10/how-fast-is-exponential-growth-or-yao-ming-confronts-the-vastness-of-the-universe/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converges by comparison test: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{e^n \sqrt{n}}\leq 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^n }=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{e })^n$$ (convergent geometric series with $r=\frac{1}{e}<1$) since $\ln(n)\leq 2\sqrt{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

In each case, I think that your easiest solution may well be the *ratio test*.

The ratio test works a lot like comparison to a geometric series, but it isn't quite as sensitive to the "non-geometric" terms of a series.

By inspection: when you use the ratio test on the two series, you should get $\frac{1}{e}$ for the first and $\frac{4}{6}$ for the second (since this encapsulates the *geometric behavior* of each).

Comment: can you repost the comment you just had? When i mean An/Bn reciprocal I'm talking about the ratio test being an+1/an, so it ends up being an+1 times the reciprocal of an. The next step of my notes in this test is usually the cancellation of some terms. I cant seem to get how to cancel n+4^n or n+6^n off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the $\;n$-th root test seems to work pretty smoothly:

$$a_n:=\frac{\log n}{e^n\sqrt n}\implies\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{\log n}}{e\sqrt{\sqrt[n]{n}}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1{e\cdot1}=\frac1e<1$$

and thus the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{n} \over \expo{n}\root{n}}}&=
\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{1/\expo{}}^{n} \over n^{\mu}}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1/2}=
\color{#00f}{\large\left.-\,\partiald{{\rm L_{i}}_{\mu}\pars{1/e}}{\mu}\right\vert_{\mu\ =\ 1/2}}
\approx 0.1183
\end{align}
$\ds{{\rm L_{i}}_{s}\pars{z}}$ is the [Polylogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).